# How to implement NetUserGetInfo function in Python using ctypes

Tags: python-3.x, winapi, ctypes

I am trying to use NetUserGetInfo in python using ctypes.

The function looks like the following as per [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/lmaccess/nf-lmaccess-netusergetinfo):

```
NET_API_STATUS NET_API_FUNCTION NetUserGetInfo(
  LPCWSTR servername,
  LPCWSTR username,
  DWORD   level,
  LPBYTE  *bufptr
);
```

I'm finding difficulty in calling the 4th argument to the function which is of type `LPBYTE  *bufptr`

my code looks like following:

```
import ctypes
from ctypes.wintypes import LPWSTR
netap = ctypes.WinDLL("Netapi32.dll")

servername = None
username = ctypes.c_wchar_p("myuser")

bufptr = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_byte)

class USER_INFO_0(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("usri0_name", LPWSTR)
    ]
usrio_name = username.bytes.decode()
level = USER_INFO_0()

response = netap.NetUserGetInfo(ctypes.byref(servername),ctypes.byref(username),level,ctypes.byref(bufptr))
print(response)
```

Getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\netusertest.py", line 17, in <module>
    response = netap.NetUserGetInfo(ctypes.byref(servername),ctypes.byref(username),level,ctypes.byref(bufptr))
TypeError: byref() argument must be a ctypes instance, not '_ctypes.PyCPointerType'
```

Any pointers are appreciated, I'm a beginner needless to say!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```py
bufptr = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_byte)
```

is a type declaration, not an instance, as your error points out, so it can't be taken by reference.  Call the type to create an instance (`ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_byte))()`) but I recommend using appropriate `wintypes` instead.

I noticed you are trying to initialize a `USER_INFO_0` instance.  This is allocated and returned by the API and must be freed as well.  `level` represent the type that will be returned as it can vary.

*servername* and *username* parameters can be passed as Unicode strings directly.

It also helps to define `.argtypes` and `.restype` to inform `ctypes` of the argument types and return type.  Don't make `ctypes` guess. If defined correctly `ctypes` will report errors if you pass a type that can't be converted to the definition.

Here is code tested on 32- and 64-bit Python with an appropriate server/user:

```py
import ctypes as ct
from ctypes import wintypes as w

# from lm.h headers.
NET_API_STATUS = w.DWORD
NERR_Success = 0

class USER_INFO_0(ct.Structure):
    _fields_ = [('usri0_name', w.LPWSTR)]

# WinDLL is appropriate as NET_API_FUNCTION is defined as __stdcall.
# This matters if the code runs under 32-bit Python.
netap = ct.WinDLL('netapi32')
netap.NetUserGetInfo.argtypes = w.LPCWSTR, w.LPCWSTR, w.DWORD, ct.POINTER(w.LPBYTE)
netap.NetUserGetInfo.restype = NET_API_STATUS
netap.NetApiBufferFree.argtypes = w.LPVOID,
netap.NetApiBufferFree.restype = NET_API_STATUS

bufptr = w.LPBYTE() # make an LPBYTE instance to hold the output parameter.

level = 0
response = netap.NetUserGetInfo('server', 'account', level, ct.byref(bufptr))
if response == NERR_Success:
    data = ct.cast(bufptr,ct.POINTER(USER_INFO_0)) # cast as indicated by level
    print(data.contents.usri0_name) # dereference pointer and access member
    netap.NetApiBufferFree(bufptr)  # free the pointer

print(response)
```